# Visual Studio 2015 shows Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c, visual-studio, file-io, visual-studio-2015

I have made a simple file reading program that runs successfully in DEV C gcc compiler, but it shows an error `Debug Assertion Failed`.
I searched and someone has asked the same question 12 days ago,
answer shows that his error was on the statement

```
if (file = fopen (name, "w+") == NULL) {
  ...
}
```

and says the separate the two statements as

```
file = fopen(name, "w+");

if (fp == NULL) { ...}
```

**My Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    int nos = 0, noc = 0, nol = 0;
    char ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Sarju.txt", "r");
    while (1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == NULL)
        {
            printf("The file didn't opened\n");
            break;
        }
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        noc++;
        if (ch == ' ')
            nos++;
        if (ch == '\n')
            nol++;
    }
    if (ch != NULL)
        fclose(fp);
    printf("Number of Space : %d\nNumber of Characters : %d\nNumber of lines : %d\n", nos, noc, nol);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}    `
```

**My Error**

> Debug Assertion failed! Program: ...o 2015\Projects\Let Us C Solutions\Debug\Let Us C Solutions.exe File: minkernel\crts\src\appcrt\stdio\fgetc.cpp Line: 43 Expression: stream.valid() For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts. (Press Retry to debug the application)

Comment: Did `fopen` fail and `fp`is `NULL`?

Comment: No!, `fopen` is not failed as  fp is not NULL, because I have run the same program on other compiler, that runs successfully

Comment: How do you know `fp` is not NULL when you run the program on *this* computer, though?

Comment: if `fp` is `NULL` that means the file didn't opened, but on running in other compiler, I've got the expected answer.

Comment: So the problem is that I have VS2015 Community?

Comment: `if (ch == NULL)
        {
            printf("The file didn't opened\n");
            break;
        }` change to `if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("The file didn't opened\n");
        }` and move to after `fp = fopen("Sarju.txt", "r");`

Comment: also `if (ch != NULL)
        fclose(fp);` --> `if (fp != NULL)
        fclose(fp);`

Comment: I am 99% sure your file location is invalid.

Comment: Nothing happens,
When a I click on retry on the error message windows,
the program crashes. So I put a printf statement to check where the heck is the problem, so the program is crashing after statement `ch = fgetc(fp);`  in `while` loop.
So is there wrong in that statement?

Comment: @V.Kravchenko Problem solved.   :-|

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems. The corrected code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int nos = 0, noc = 0, nol = 0;
    int ch; /* `int`, not `char` */
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Sarju.txt", "r");
    while (1)
    {
        /*ch = fgetc(fp); After the below `if`, not here */
        if (fp == NULL) /* `fp`, not `ch` */
        {
            printf("The file didn't opened\n");
            break;
        }
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        noc++;
        if (ch == ' ')
            nos++;
        if (ch == '\n')
            nol++;
    }
    if (fp != NULL) /* `fp`, not `ch` */
        fclose(fp);
    printf("Number of Space : %d\nNumber of Characters : %d\nNumber of lines : %d\n", nos, noc, nol);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

1. I used `int` as `fgetc` returns an `int`, not `char`.
2. You should check if `fp` is not `NULL`, not `ch`.
3. `ch = fgetc(fp);` was at the wrong place.